# spring-cloud-stream sample projects raises NoSuchBeanDefinitionException of KafkaStreamsFunctionProcessor

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm trying to touch spring-cloud-stream, and creating a sample project of the [official blog](https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/02/stream-processing-with-spring-cloud-stream-and-apache-kafka-streams-part-1-programming-model).

Implementation is totally same as the article.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SimpleConsumerApplication {

   @Bean
   public java.util.function.Consumer<KStream<String, String>> process() {

       return input ->
               input.foreach((key, value) -> {
                   System.out.println("Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
               });
   }
}
```

I've selected `Cloud Stream` and `Spring for Apache Kafka Stream` on [Spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/), and added `ShadowJar`. Now my `build.gradle` is like this.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '6.1.0'
}

group = 'com.lipsum'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class': 'com.lipsum.kafkastream.KafkastreamApplication')
    }
}

shadowJar {
    archiveBaseName.set('kafka-stream-practice')
    archiveClassifier.set('')
    archiveVersion.set('')
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2020.0.2")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I execute the uber jar, but springboot application fails to recognize the bean.

```
$ java -jar kafka-stream-practice.jar --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-in-0.destination=kafka-stream-practice
...
22:47:21.162 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaStreamsFunctionProcessorInvoker' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/function/KafkaStreamsFunctionAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'kafkaStreamsFunctionProcessorInvoker' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KafkaStreamsFunctionProcessor' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KafkaStreamsFunctionProcessor' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I don't think the implementation has any problems. Do I miss some dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a quick maven project from the initialize and it starts fine. There was a known bug on the last release (`3.0.11`) which was fixed since then on the snapshot. You can fix the issue by adding the boot actuator dependency to the project or by upgrading the binder to the latest snapshot. Could you try the maven approach? If the problem still persists, please share a reproducible sample, and then we will take a look.

Comment: Thanks. After removing shadowJar, it's built successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It works after removing `shadowJar` and instead uses `bootJar` task of Spring Boot Gradle plugin.